# Windows 10 Right-Click Context Menu on screen

Tags: windows, desktop, windows-10-preview

Since today I cannot open the Context Menu (right click) on the Windows 10 home screen.

When I right click, nothing happens. There are no errors.

How do I resolve this?

Windows 10 Pro Preview (build 10547)

Comment: When did it start? Have you restarted the PC?

Comment: Sure! Couple of times. I scan my pc for a viruses, trying to find solution in internet but nothing found

Comment: [one solution here](http://www.tenforums.com/general-discussion/11777-right-click-not-working.html)

Comment: Does context menu pop up in all other scenarios?

Comment: Yes. All other, like start-button context menu - all work fine

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of solutions out there but this finally worked and well.  Create a batch file that restarts your explorer process.  Add a shortcut to it on your desktop so that when right (taskbar icons and area) and left click menus (Start Menu area) stop working just click the shortcut, and explorer restarts without needing a reboot.

```
@ECHO OFF
echo.
TASKKILL /F /IM explorer.exe
echo.
start explorer.exe
echo.
echo SUCCESS
echo.
```

Comment: You should consider not submitting the exact same answer to multiple questions.  The underline problem that causes this problem, cannot be solved, by simply restarting explorer.exe