# Taskbar Context Menu / Right Click broken after 21H1 Update on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Since my most recent Windows 10 update to version 21H1 with I cannot open the Context Menu (right click) on the Windows 10 Taskbar apps.

This is *specifically* on the apps themselves and not the Task Tray, Start Menu, Cortana, Search or Task View -- all these worked correctly.

Just like [some](https://superuser.com/questions/978678/windows-10-right-click-context-menu-on-screen) [other](https://superuser.com/questions/1030315/restore-right-click-menu-on-taskbar-icon-in-windows-10) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/1021405/windows-10-taskbar-right-click-doesnt-work-properly), as some of the comments addressed on these, their workarounds (such as restarting explorer, restarting the tile service) and answers (such as fixing Local Group Policy for context menu permissions on the Taskbar) did **not** fix the issue. This also displays *no errors* at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the reason *my* Context Menu was broken in the latest update was due to [StartIsBack](https://www.startisback.com/#) not being compatible with Windows updates after the 21H1 installation before version SIB 2.9.11.

SIB had not recognised it needed to update yet so I was still on 2.9.9.

I simply updated to 2.9.11 manually by downloading it from the website and now the issue is fixed and I didn't need to restart Explorer, my PC or any tile servers.

Answer (score 0):

When a variety of other solutions did not work, [Fix the right-click Context Menu on the Start Menu and Taskbar through PowerShell](https://www.itechtics.com/fix-right-click-not-working/#Fix_the_right-click_Context_Menu_on_the_Start_Menu_and_Taskbar_through_PowerShell) once fixed broken right-click context menus in a ***Windows 10 Home** Version **21H1** OS build **19043.1083** Experience **Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0*** task bar.

This solution calls for running PowerShell as Administrator, and then running the following command:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}
```

The command runs for quite a long time and error messages may be ignored.

After following these instructions, right-click context menus in the task bar started working again (reboot not needed).

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.